# How to use std::copy if an explicit type conversion is necessary between source and destination type

Tags: c++

Consider

```
struct foo{};

struct bar{
    bar(const foo& f){}
};
```

And imagine that I have a

```
std::vector<foo> vec;
```

and I want to convert this to a `std::vector<bar> out`. I can use

```
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(out));
```

to do that since `bar` is not `explicit`. However, I need `bar` to be `explicit`! But then the `back_inserter` no longer works. What changes do I need to make to the `std::copy` parameters to somehow include the explicit `bar(<iteratee>)`?

Comment: Use std::transform instead?

Answer (score 12):

```
std::transform(
    vec.begin(),
    vec.end(),
    std::back_inserter(out),
    [](const foo& f){
        return bar(f);
    }
);
```

will do it.